# How to improve this function for converting columns to date types over a list of dataframes

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes. I have a function currently - it is limited. It works by inputting the dataframes within this list that have a certain column name - and converts this column to date type.

Limitations:

- You have to define the columns which you know have this column - if you include a dataframe that does not include this column it would throw an error. It'd be good if it could work over all dataframes in the list - even if they don't include the specified column
- Currently, it takes one column name, however a dataframe may contain other columns which could be converted to dates. It'd be good for the function to accept multiple column name inputs.

Here is my function currently:

```
repair_dates3 <- function(data, df_list, col_name) {
  lapply(df_list, function(x) {
    data[[x]][[col_name]] <<- as.Date(data[[x]][[col_name]], format = "%Y-%m-%d")
  })
  return(data)
}
```

You call it like this:

```
repair_dates3(data, c("dataframe1", "dataframe2", "dataframe3"), "Date")
```

Any ideas how I can improve this?

Many thanks

Comment: did you try col_name=c('nameA',nameB','nameC') ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is simpler and more flexible. It allows a vector of data frames and a vector of column names to be defined and processed by the function.
Untested, since there is no example data set.

```
repair_dates3 <- function(x, col_names, format = "%Y-%m-%d") {
  x[col_names] <- lapply(x[col_names], as.Date, format = format)
  x
}

df_list <- c("dataframe1", "dataframe2", "dataframe3")
cols <- c("Date", "Date.2")
data[df_list] <- lapply(data[df_list], repair_dates3, cols)
```

Another solution, maybe closer to the question post, is to define a function that takes care of the outer `lapply` call. This will call an inner, private function `f`.

```
repair_dates4 <- function(x, which_dfs, col_names, format = "%Y-%m-%d") {
  f <- function(x, d, format = "%Y-%m-%d"){
    x[d] <- lapply(x[d], as.Date, format = format)
    x
  }
  x[which_dfs] <- lapply(x[which_dfs], f, col_names, format = format)
  x
}

data <- repair_date4(data, df_list, cols)
```